# Linker cannot find MKErrorDomain

Tags: iphone, mapkit

After adding a test for error code to MKReverseGeocoder's callback, got a linker error indicating that _MKErrorDomain is not defined:

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // some useful but irrelevant code removed here...

    // if the error is not permanent, try again
    NSString *errorDomain = [error domain];
    NSInteger errorCode = [error code];

    if ([errorDomain isEqualToString:MKErrorDomain] && errorCode != MKErrorPlacemarkNotFound) {
        [self scheduleReverseLookup];
    }
}
```

Linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_MKErrorDomain", referenced from:
      -[Tracker reverseGeocoder:didFailWithError:] in Tracker.o
```

Note that MapKit is being linked in and works fine with the test for MKErrorDomain removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue, which is also true for `arvm7`, with latest iOS 4.3 / Xcode 4.0.1.

Looks like `<MapKit/MKTypes.h>` is missing his little brother `MKTypes.o` in MapKit binary...

Anyway, a quick (and dirty) fix is to use `@"MKErrorDomain"` instead of the `MKErrorDomain` constant.

Or a little bit better, in any case this is fixed later, or if you reference it a lot, you can redefine it :

```
#define MKErrorDomain @"MKErrorDomain"
```