# iPhone - linker error when using constants

Tags: iphone, constants, linker-errors

Why does I have a linker error on this :

```
- (void) reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    if ([[error domain] isEqualToString:MKErrorDomain] && [error code] == MKErrorPlacemarkNotFound) {
          Do things
    }
}


Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_MKErrorDomain", referenced from:
      -[MapController reverseGeocoder:didFailWithError:] in MapController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

MapKit framework is included.
MapKit/MapKit.h is imported.
Everything works fine with MapKit calls when I do not have those lines...

Comment: [`Possibly related`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494383/linker-cannot-find-mkerrordomain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494383/linker-cannot-find-mkerrordomain) before. Hope it's going to help you.